# Maven secure HTTPS repository and JDK5

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, java-5

Since January 2020, maven has switched their repo from HTTP to HTTPS.
In order my project (running with Java 5 + maven 3.1.1) to download the repos i changed in my pom.xml the repos to look to: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
This worked fine and now maven tries to access the dependencies from the secure repository.
Trying to build/clean my project i faced following issues:

**Issue 1**
Trying to mvn clean my project without any further arguments i receive following error:
*Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): peer not authenticated -> [Help 1]*

I tried to bypass the error by adding following arguments:
*mvn -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true clean*

New error:
 *Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Remote host closed connection during handshake: SSL peer shut down incorrectly -> [Help 1]*

Further attemp by adding alos the following argument: *-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1*
Resolves to a new error:

*Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): TLSv1.2 -> [Help 1]*

**Issue 2**
I tried to with a different approach by using the certificate provided from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/
I import the certificate into a trust store and tried to use this with the following maven command:

*mvn  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\PortableApps\trust.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=pass -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\PortableApps\trust.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=pass clean*

The error is the same as previous again
*Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): peer not authenticated -> [Help 1]*

I start to believe, that this is not goign to work with Java 5 due to the limitations of the JVM.  As a last resolution, i find the usage of the insecure repo http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/ but i want to go do this as my very last option. Any further suggestions?

**Note**

- On another project with Java 7, i was able to resolve all the issues by using the latest maven version 3.6.3
- Since the project is compatible only with Java 5, i am limited in
  using maven version up to 3.1.1

Comment: You can use toolchain to compile and test your project with JDK 5 whereas Maven runs with JDK 7 .... https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html

Comment: is this suggested as a resolution as what i am trying to do will not work with jdk5 or is this just a workaround ? Thank you for your reply

Comment: Try to use proxy: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html , proxy server should provide ordinary http for your maven client, but will connect itself to maven's https repository, since issue is in outdated client - should help.

Comment: The other solution would be to use a repository manager like Nexus ...This is a setup I strongly recommend for running Maven etc. within a corporate environment which will handle the https part...also I would recommend to upgrade your Maven version  also you can change the configuration of your project and build with JDK7+ and define the `target to JDK 5` ..? and I strongly recommend to use the https connection.....

Comment: Alex Chernyshev, i cannot go with this option, as in this case i will need to force others who compile the application on different environments, to create a proxy just for this case as well.

Comment: khmarbaise, i will have a look on your first proposal as also about the Nexus. As i said, i am unable to go above maven 3.1.1 version due to incompatibility with Java 5.
Building with JDK7 is unfortunately not an option. We are sort of obligated in maintaining Java 5. 

My question though, is if there as solution (without using nexus, proxies, etc) to this issue or not due to Java 5. This is not yet clear to me.

Comment: @Stephan I am not sure whether this is clear to you, so let me add: You can build an application _with_ JDK 1.7 _for_ Java 5. You can later run it on JDK 1.5 even if you build it with JDK 1.7.

Comment: @JF Meier  i am aware of that. but as i said on my comment above, i am forced to use java 5 only.  Not greater, for any kind of reason (build/run). I have solved my issue by using the insecure repo http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/ , but still i am wondering if there is a way of using Java 5 and still use the https.

Comment: @Stephan I find it strange that you are "forced" to do something like that. Even if this a guideline or rule of your company/project, it would be worth the effort to speak with the relevant people and ask them to change it.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and your replies. But we are going out of scope right now :) . I believe the question is rather simple. Can all those proposals i read online for the new secure maven repo, work with Java 5 ? If yes, what i am missing? Lets just exclude the fact of the existance of Java 6 or 7.

Comment: Looks that this cannot work with Java 5 due to TLS suport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the insecure maven repo http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/ in order to make it work with Java 5 (build/run).

Alternative, as some already suggested in the comments, you may use JDK 7 for your build process in order to download the dependencies from the secure maven repository and Java 5 for running your app.

As it seems, there is no way in accessing the secure maven repo while using Java 5 due to the lack of TLSv1.2 support which maven seems to use (https://central.sonatype.org/articles/2018/May/04/discontinued-support-for-tlsv11-and-below/?__hstc=31049440.13cc707ef0d169390d4d7ac8ba12c78e.1571910247825.1579506965027.1580304556973.4&__hssc=31049440.1.1580304556973&__hsfp=1122763312)